# Can anyone see any issues with styling the native Twitter widget with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter

I've managed to get this working on Chrome (not tested anything else yet) and was wondering if anyone could see any problems with this method of styling the native Twitter widget?

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $("#twitter-widget-0").contents().find('head').append('<link href="_css/twitter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
});
```

It's certainly let me restyle any elements that I needed to.

I'm including that after the markup for the widget.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, you can see on the footer of this page http://www.bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/office-365-v2013/theme/Flexo/page/Home/customize a twitter widget with custom css applied using script, this works in all major browsers never get any problem with it.

Comment: From what I can see there, that site isn't using the native Twitter widget (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines).